# How to obtain link inside of a DIV nested in a TD with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

***Problem:*** "Easy" way (`pd.read_html()`) of obtaining table information with Pandas isn't working for my use case.

It's only pulling what I believe is the label text, and it's got this newb confuzzled. What I need is at least the link *(to pdf)* text.

Table was obtained from an ASPX page via Requests/BeautifulSoup. I was able to get that table into a Pandas DataFrame without issue.

> **If you use the link below, please copy and paste it as to remove the referrer URL. My luck, some IT guy changes the code, breaking the
> script earlier than needed. lol**

[Link to page](https://ujsportal.pacourts.us/CaseSearch) *(you'll have to manually search using the variables defined in the script)*.

**Scraper.py:**

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# User-defined variables
SearchBy = 'DateFiled'
FiledStartDate = '2020-01-01'
FiledEndDate = '2020-01-01'
County = 'Luzerne'
MDJSCourtOffice = 'MDJ-11-1-01'

host = "ujsportal.pacourts.us"
base_url = "https://" + host
search_url = base_url + "/CaseSearch"

# Headers are required. Do not change.
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,\
               image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': host,
    'Origin': base_url,
    'Referer': search_url,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) \
                   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0'
}

# Open session request to obtain proper cookies
ses = requests.session()
req = ses.get(search_url, headers=headers)

# Get required hidden token so we can search
tree = html.fromstring(req.content)
veri_token = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/input/@value")[0]

# Import search criteria from user-defined variables
payload = {
    'SearchBy': SearchBy,
    'AdvanceSearch': 'true',
    'FiledStartDate': FiledStartDate,
    'FiledEndDate': FiledEndDate,
    'County': County,
    'MDJSCourtOffice': MDJSCourtOffice,
    '__RequestVerificationToken': veri_token
}

# Make search request
results = ses.post(
    search_url,
    data=payload,
    headers=headers
)

# Save html page to disk
with open("tmp/test_draft1.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(results.text)

# Open local HTML page for processing
with open("tmp/test_draft1.html") as html:
    page = bs(html, 'lxml')

table = page.find('table', {'id': 'caseSearchResultGrid'})

# Save table as sperate HTML for later audit
with open("tmp/test_draft1_table.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(table.prettify())


# Remove unneeded tags so we don't have to do it in Pandas
def clean_tags(page):
    for tag in table.select('div.bubble-text'):
        tag.decompose()
    for tag in table.select('div.modal'):
        tag.decompose()
    for tag in table.find_all(['th', 'tr', 'td'], class_="display-none"):
        tag.decompose()
    for tag in table.select('tfoot'):
        tag.decompose()


clean_tags(page)

# Start constructing dataset
columns = table.find('thead').find_all('th')
column_names = [c.get_text() for c in columns]

table_rows = table.find('tbody').find_all('tr')

case_info = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.get_text() for tr in td]
    case_info.append(row)

# Forward dataset to Pandas for analysis
df = pd.DataFrame(case_info, columns=column_names)
df.columns.values[16] = "Docket URL"

if SearchBy == 'DateFiled':
    df.drop(columns=['Event Type',
            'Event Status', 'Event Date', 'Event Location'], inplace=True)

df
exit("Scrape Complete!")
```

**This works to pull the docket pdf link by itself into a seperate list. But does not update the cell properly.**

```py
for row in table_rows:
    row_processed = []
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    if len(cells) == 17:
        docket_url = base_url + cells[16].find('a')['href']
        row_processed.append(docket_url)
```

**Current `print(df)` truncated output snippet:**

```
              Docket Number  ...                 Docket URL
0  MJ-11101-CR-0000001-2020  ...  Docket SheetCourt Summary
1  MJ-11101-CR-0000003-2020  ...  Docket SheetCourt Summary
2  MJ-11101-CR-0000006-2020  ...  Docket SheetCourt Summary
3  MJ-11101-NT-0000081-2020  ...  Docket SheetCourt Summary
```

**Needed `print(df)` truncated output snippet:**

```
              Docket Number  ...                 Docket URL
0  MJ-11101-CR-0000001-2020  ...  https://link/to/docketPDF
1  MJ-11101-CR-0000003-2020  ...  https://link/to/docketPDF
2  MJ-11101-CR-0000006-2020  ...  https://link/to/docketPDF
3  MJ-11101-NT-0000081-2020  ...  https://link/to/docketPDF
```

Comment: When I `print(df)` I get the following as and output: `[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Info Sheet]
Index: []]`

Comment: "_I have a feeling I am going to have to parse each column in BS and send that to Pandas_". You should probably do that

Comment: I only included a snippet of the entire code. Due to what I am scraping, I would rather not put the entire code out there. One bit of code missing is the definition for ```HTMLSource```. 

```python
HTMLSource = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')```

But that does no good either since ```driver.page_source``` points to the actual url via a ```driver.get(url)```. That code would have to change to point to a local html with the table html above.

I have a feeling I am going to have to parse each column in BS and send that to Pandas.

Comment: Could you provide the source if available? I tried the data with the `table snippet` provided and loaded it and get the results @MendelG gets.

Comment: @JoeThor, I am not at liberty to provide the actual url to the original source. It's why I included the already rendered table html. In order to get anything out of df, one would have to direct soup to a local html file with that table contents in it. See above comment.

Comment: @MendelG, so much for the KISS method. lol. If I was writing a webpage, I would almost never put a div inside of a table. But this, I think, would also happen if it was an image inside of a cell. I'm new to scraping and python in general. But after further searching around, I came up with the for loop option.

Comment: I take it the source url is not one you wish to share? Or is not freely available to Joe and Jane Bloggs?

Comment: @QHaar, not one willing to share. It's ethical scraping (a state government website), so don't worry. I just have a client *(me actually :) )* that has to keep some sort of journalistic integrity. The scraper is related to a news story, and since stack overflow is publicly searchable... All of the relevant table data that needs to be scraped is there, though (names changed for "anonymity," of course).

Comment: The full table has 19 columns, the last of which is the one containing the url. Unfortunately, that particular row doesn't have a column name. I have since changed the main code in preparation to use for loops. I'll change the original question to reflect that in a few minutes.

Comment: how about `html_page.split('href=\"')` or maybe `html_page.split('target="_blank">')`

Comment: @HankW, I only need to put the url link into a cell. I don't currently need to obtain information inside of that pdf. Although, that will eventually be a feature embedded into the crawler. I plan on using tabula.py for that. I like that idea of using a split screen in the webdriver though. That may come in handy later on. Never thought of that.

Comment: yeah you just need to splited_html_page.forEach(regex find) <- Not an actual code!

Comment: @HankW, I am thinking a combination of ```if len(td) >18``` and ```tbl.append()``` is going to be a better option. I just have to learn and figure out the right syntax and location in the row iteration. ..or make the entire code longer and less user-friendly and define each and every column using a dictionary and xpath.

Comment: I think you have to replace the anchor tag with the value of its href. then panda should serve the rest. Make a strip() copy and try replace `<a class="icon-wrapper" href=` and `target="_blank"> <img class="icon-size" alt="Info Sheet" src="https://example.com/imgs/svg-defs.svg?v=x#icon-document" title="Info Sheet"/> <label class="link-text">Info Sheet</label> </a>` with `" "`

Comment: @HankW, I've rewritten some of the main code since. But one snippet that works to just get the data from a "bare" row is this. ```for row in table_rows:
    row_processed = []
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    if len(cells) == 17:
        sheet_url = base_url + cells[16].find('a')['href']
        row_processed.append(sheet_url) ``` But I can't figure out where to stick it in the row iteration with the rest of the content.

Comment: @JoeThor I updated the information and included the url to the page being scraped.

Comment: @QHarr, I updated the information and included the url to the page being scraped.

Comment: @MendelG, the entire script is up if you want to try again. Thanks.

Comment: I can't view so difficult to comment much but can you assign the pdf urls as a column after creating the initial dataframe? Either with direct assignment, if same number of rows, or by a left join on  Docket # if you create an initial dataframe with docket # and urls? Urls you are likely able to retrieve by combining td:nth-of-type() to target a specific column and an attribute=value selector for the href.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: @QHarr, I didn't think of ETL of two dfs. I'm new to all of it. If this was two csv's, I'd be able to do it. Odd thing is, my end goal is to get this into a csv so I can merge it with something else.  LOL And the table in question should make it somewhat easy. The first two columns I removed with that page clean seems to be their form of indexing. I'd rather do it in one shot if I can. I know updating that cell in place using soup is possible. For the life of me, I can't figure out how. Yet I figured out how to scrape an aspx page that requires a veri-token (without using selenium).

Comment: BTW, this is my FIRST scraper project. I picked a doozy. Shoulda saw it before they updated the website. Before it was still ASPX, but everything was done via  view_states.

Comment: If you can use bs4 to extract the links as a list of hrefs, and that list is the same length as the dataframe index then you can just direct assign.

Comment: @QHarr, that should definitely work. The list will always have the same length as the dataframe. Not the ideal way I wanted to do it, but a solution is a solution. I'll get back to coding it tonight.

Comment: @QHarr, answer posted. Thanks for the help and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with the help and guidance of QHarr in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67728275/how-to-obtain-link-inside-of-a-div-nested-in-a-td-with-beautifulsoup#comment119946917_67728275) of the original question, I was able to come up with a solution. As with anything coding related, I am sure this isn't the only answer.

Anyway... After trying to get these two iteration loops integrated the way I wanted, concatenating two Pandas DataFrames works.

**Case Info Data:**

```py
case_info = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.get_text() for tr in td]
    case_info.append(row)
```

**Docket URLs:** *(produces a list with the urls)*

```py
docket_urls = []
for drow in table_rows:
    docket_sheets = []
    cells = drow.find_all("td")
    if len(cells) == 17:
        docket_url = base_url + cells[16].find('a')['href']
        docket_sheets.append(docket_url)
    docket_urls.append(docket_sheets)
```

***DataFrames:***

```py
# Import case info dataset to Pandas
df_case_info = pd.DataFrame(case_info, columns=column_names)
df_case_info.columns.values[16] = "Docket Text"  # Rename col = easy to drop

df_case_info.drop(columns=['Docket Text'], inplace=True)

if SearchBy == 'DateFiled':
    df_case_info.drop(columns=['Event Type',
            'Event Status', 'Event Date', 'Event Location'], inplace=True)

# Import docket URLs into Pandas
df_docket_urls = pd.DataFrame(docket_urls, columns={'Docket URL'})

# Concatonate both DataFrames into one
df_mdj = pd.concat([df_case_info, df_docket_urls], axis=1)
```

I still want to learn how to do this the way I originally planned. But if it's not broke, don't fix it, right?

**To those who helped, Thank You. This is what I call a Suckcess. :)**